# Dealing with edited questions/answers

Tags: discussion, editing, best-practices

While it's not something usual, I've noticed that sometimes people edit my question or answer with a more complex notation or incorrect information/formulas. While I don't think this is done with malicious intent, it has sometimes confused people when I'm either asking or explaining something, as I don't always notice that my post has been edited with such radical changes.

What is the best course of action to take in this case? Is there a way to block a question/answer so it can only by edited with my approval? And hopefully it doesn't happen but, if someone edits an answer with blatant incorrect information, is it possible to report that person?

Comment: Looking through your post history, I'm not seeing anything like what you're describing here. Some people have correctly changed $cos$ to $\cos$ or added tags, but nothing that changes the meaning or adds "complex" maths. Could you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: I agree with Kyle. I had a look at the first few [recent edits to your posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1012995?UserId=204345), and there is nothing obvious that matches your description. It would be helpful if you can point to a few examples of threads with the behaviour that's bothering you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can roll-back edits that you don't approve of (click on the date/time of the edit where it is displayed at the bottom of the post to view the edit history where these control are displayed).

There is no user-accessible means of preventing edits (and locks are only used by the moderators for special or extreme cases).